# Probability of two coins having the same bias

Tags: probability

Assume that we have two coins and also assume that probability of heads for coin A is x and probability of heads for coin B is y. Given the below two random and independent trails:

```
Coin A: H, T, H 
Coin B: T, H, H, T, H
```

What is the probability that x = y?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking from a Bayesian point of view (in which case, you have not supplied a prior and your question is unclear), or a frequentist point of view (in which case you'll have to give more information, but it's probably unanswerable), or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b Actually I'm not sure how to frame the question. But my intuition is this: for example in longer trials if coin A produces much more Heads than Tails, and coin B produces approximately equal number of Heads and Tails I would say that with a high probability their biases are different. What I would like to have is a more formal expression of this intuition.

Comment: If you use a uniform prior for $X$ and $Y$, viz., $P(X) \sim Beta(1,1), P(Y) \sim Beta(1,1)$  then you will surmise that the posteriors $X \sim p(X|data)=Beta(3,2), Y \sim p(Y|data)=Beta(4,3)$. But $P(X=Y|data)$ is almost certainly 0. But you may be interested in $\Delta(\epsilon|data)=Pr(|X-Y|<\epsilon|data)$. Better yet, if your prior is $Beta(a,b)$ with the weakly informative $(a=2,b=2)$, then  $\Delta(\epsilon|a,b,data)$ is something worth studying. If this is close to your needs, please confirm, and I'll write up the details.

Comment: from the input you provided - nothing of substance can be concluded. Need a larger sample.

Comment: @adhg The sample I have given is just an example, you can assume more samples, what I ask for is a general method to solve the problem. (Sorry for this very late reply, I hope you can answer)